# Php & MySql selection from string seperated by commas

Tags: php, mysql

I have this:

```
$string = "battery,lighter,phone";
```

I have a table `users` that has each user's tags.

How is it possible to `select` using sql `where tags = $string` and `where email = '$usermail'` ;

I just want to retrieve data based on `user email` and `user stored tags` that are separated by comma in the table like the above string

Comment: You can compare multiple fields in where clause using comma sepreaded

Comment: Please tell me  that  tags entry are like `battery,light,phone` or just `battery` and others for every users in `user` table. So i can provide solution according that..:)

Comment: I have more than one tags for each user, so basically i want to use user's email to select all user's values and i will use "while" to echo all user's saved Tag names from raw Tags. Any help? Values that are stored in raw Tags are seperated by comma: shoes,lighters,pants,flash etc

Comment: Er. Anurag Jain can you give me contact information with you  ?

Comment: @Er.AnuragJain can you give me contact information with you ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only selecting for one tag you could use

```
 select bits where tag like '%select_value' and email = 'email_value'
```

If you need to pick out multiple tags you'll need to parse out the csv. That's a larger challenge.

Comment: I have more than one tags for each user,

Comment: I have more than one tags for each user, so basically i want to use user's email to select all user's values and i will use "while" to echo all user's saved Tag names from raw Tags. Any help? Values that are stored in raw Tags are seperated by comma: shoes,lighters,pants,flash etc

Comment: Im confused - are you trying to select a user that has certain tags or just get the tags for a certain user?

Comment: Ok folks. I have a Table categories with id, categoryname. categoryname has: id=1 categoryname = batteries, id=2 categoryname = flashes, id=3 categoryname glasses. The Second table is users. Users have id, user_eimal, my_choices. every user has store into my_choices the category name that wants to appear. So for example user George with user_email xxxxx@xxx.com has store in my_choices: batteries,glasses Now i want to bring up records from table products where categoryname is, the values that user george has stored into my_choices. Products has id, p_title, categoryname.

Comment: See my answer above.  I use the product's 'catgoryname' and the User's my_choices to perform a join between product and users.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER UPDATED: Given the tables as listed in another's comment:

```
SELECT p.id, p.p_title, p.categoryname, u.id, u.user_email, u.my_choices
  FROM users u
  JOIN products p
    ON FIND_IN_SET(p.categoryname, u.my_choices)
 WHERE u.email = 'email_value'
```

MySQL has a [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function that may suit your purposes.  In this particular case, all of the products that have a 'categoryname' within the user's 'my_choices' will be returned.

Let me know if this works for you,

john...